# std::cout not showing on screen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cout

This is a fairly simple problem I can't get my head around. It was working before and suddenly now that I'm using std::cout, in the Visual Studio 2013 output window I do not see the output, but I see a bunch of background executions happening. I feel I have messed up something. This is App Game Kit project using C++.

Here's the simple code to output:

```
#include "template.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace AGK;

app App;

void app::Begin(void)
{
    agk::SetVirtualResolution (1024, 768);
    agk::SetClearColor( 151,170,204 ); 
    agk::SetSyncRate(60,0);
    agk::SetScissor(0,0,0,0);
    std::cout << "Hello";    // SIMPLE PRINT
}

void app::Loop (void)
{
    agk::Print( agk::ScreenFPS() );
    agk::Sync();
    // std::cout << "Hello";    // TRIED HERE TOO (works like update() in Unity3D)
}
```

This is what my debug window is showing, instead of printing "Hello":

[image]

FYI, the program is working perfectly without any errors. Am I looking at the wrong window? where can find my output?

Comment: What is the PDB file?

Comment: Your program, as shown above, never produces any output, it just queues it. There's no call to `flush` or `endl` or anything like that.

Comment: What if you write a plain C++ program without "AGK"? You can redirect where streams write, like e.g. to a file or discard the output entirely. What you show above seem to be internal messages (see `OutputDebugString()`) that were thrown into a debug window in earlier VS versions, so they are rather unrelated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You don't have to manually call flush unless you want to be sure you see the output right away. It has to produce output at least by the time the program ends, when `cout` is destroyed.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley His screenshot above doesn't show the program ending. Also, it only "has" to produce output if you allow `cout` to be destroyed. If, for example, the program terminates abnormally, ...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I tried making a simple C++ program on VS. Same problem. Even the console window shuts down immediately, and the console window has pretty much the same type of executions. Here's the code: 

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
 return 0;
}

Comment: Well, program starts, console window is created, receives output and then it is closed when the program exits. Set a breakpoint or insert a delay to keep it open. BTW: Next time, please reduce your code to a minimal example before asking here.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/79u1nk871/

Comment: Or run the program from a command line.

Comment: @Daqs It sounds like all your programs are doing what you're asking them to do, you're just not asking them to do what you want them to do.

Comment: `std::cout` is *not* connected to the Visual Studio output window, it's connected to the console that the program is running with. If your program has no console, `cout` is completely disconnected and you won't see anything. If the program creates its own console window when you start it, it will close the console window as soon as it completes and you won't get a chance to see the output. That's just the way Windows and Visual Studio work.

Answer (score 1):

for logging, i write my entries to a file. here is the Contents of my log method in cpp:

```
void MyFileUtils::log(string msg)
{
ofstream log("logfile.txt", ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
log << msg << endl;
return;
}
```

i then just call this whenever i want to log something. i have it as a singleton. Then i just look in my media subfolder to see the contents of logfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try using this before you return from the method:
   
    `log.flush();
    log.close();`